# How to delete all the issues in the Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm facing a "trouble in the bitbucket". I made a batch that connects the bitbucket and the trello, but now I'm facing more issues.
     That said, how can I delete all the issues listed in my repo without editing them individually?

Answer (score 4):

You may just import zip archive with JSON file named `db-1.0.json` like this:

```
{
    "milestones": [],
    "attachments": [],
    "versions": [],
    "comments": [],
    "meta": {
        "default_milestone": null,
        "default_assignee": null,
        "default_kind": "bug",
        "default_component": null,
        "default_version": null
    },
    "components": [],
    "issues": [],
    "logs": []
}
```

For import archive go to **Your repository -> Settings -> Issue -> Import & Export**.